# Help merging free space partition with Macintosh HD partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I installed and then un-installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook Air (OS X El Capitan 10.11.6). I had split the hard drive into 2 partitions - Macintosh partition of 60.6 GB and now I have a free space partition of 59.6 GB. I'm unable to merge these 2 partitions. I have included some screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Output from `diskutil list`:

[image]

Output from `diskutil cs list`:

[image]

Output from `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`:

[image]

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Sophia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before issuing the command to merge the free space, you will need to fix an error in the GUID Partition Table (GPT). The "Recovery HD" labeled partition with the identifier `disk0s3` has a GUID of `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`. The correct value should be `426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.

One way, to correct this error, would be to boot from [OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and enter the following commands in a Terminal application window.

```
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk /dev/disk0
gpt add -i 3 -b 119050312 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

> Note: The **three** keys you need to hold down to start "OS X Internet Recovery" are <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Once the above commands have been entered, you can restart the computer back to El Capitan.

The Terminal application command to merge the free space is given below.

```
diskutil  resizevolume  /dev/disk0s2  R
```

This command will move `/dev/disk0s3` to the bottom of `disk0` while resizing `/dev/disk0s2` to maximum size.